# App crashes on Window.java getContext()

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I updated IntellijIDEA and now my app crashes everytime I open it, With the debug tool I can see the line where it stops,

```
Window.Java class...

public final Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
```

is in the return of that function, the object does not come null and i don't know why it crashes..
the return is called several times I counted like 50 or more and there is one loop where it crashes.
this function is called from `setContentView(R.layout.main);` on the `intializecomponents()` of myActivity class this `setContentView(R.layout.main);` function calls inside the `getContext()` of the window.Java class

```
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    getWindow().setContentView(layoutResID);
    initActionBar();
}
```

and again the error happens here.. in the return who is called a lot of times..

```
public final Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
```

UPDATE......

The problem was with the permissions in Main.Xml I don't know what is the correct way to set them

here is what I have..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" ></uses-permission>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:src="@drawable/folder"
            android:contentDescription=""/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcomeText"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Am I doing it Right?

Comment: can you post the stacktrace

Comment: Does ./gradlew clean help?

Comment: The error ocurs with the permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" ></uses-permission> if I don't put them the try catch works well in the internet operations I want to make, it catches the error and nothing happens, but why is that error, i put the permissions settings in the Main.Xml after LinearLayout and before my Controls definitions..

Comment: the stacktrace gives this error
http://pastebin.com/N1tPZdxR

Comment: I edited the question there is my Main.Xml i don't know how to if I'm setting the permissions Well..?

Comment: Are u trying on emulator if not try on another device had same trace with USB stuff

Comment: They Must Be in the AndroidManifest.Xml File thank you all